# Java, Creating an object vector that should have n zeros in it's array after compilation

Tags: java, vector, interface, abstract, extends

This is kind of hard but I will try to make my question as clear as possible. 
So I'm working on a project that deals with operations on vectors. I have different classes for different dimensions: Vector3D, Vector5D and VectorND. So I have interface and abstract class that describe methods like Sum, Subtraction etc. And for result of operation I create a new object Vector where I put coordinates after sum/subtraction etc. So here is the part of code as an example:

```
interface sample
{
    Vector Sum(Vector vec);
    Vector Subtraction(Vector vec);
    int Product(Vector vec);
    boolean Compare(Vector vec);
    String ToString();
}
abstract class Vector implements sample
{       
    int[] coordinates;  
     public Vector (int[] coordinates)
     {
         this.coordinates=coordinates;
     }
    protected abstract Vector resVec();     
    public Vector Sum(Vector vec)
    {   
        Vector result = resVec();
        if (this.coordinates.length == vec.coordinates.length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i< vec.coordinates.length; i++)
            {
                result.coordinates[i] = this.coordinates[i] + vec.coordinates[i];
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Can't sum vectors of different length");
        }
        return result;
```

Here is have protected abstart Vector resVec(); - method that creates new vector with length that depends on dimension of vectors that we operate with. 
Example of realization for Vector3D:

```
class Vector3D extends Vector

{

public Vector3D(int n1,int n2,int n3) 
{
       super(new int[]{n1,n2,n3});
}

public Vector3D resVec()
{
    Vector3D resVec = new Vector3D(0,0,0);
    return resVec;
}
```

So here I create a new vector with length 3 and fill it with zeros. I need to create same vector for VectorND. Like this:

```
    class VectorND extends Vector
{
    public VectorND(int...n) 
    {       
            super(n);
    }
    public VectorND resVec()
    {
        VectorND resVec = new VectorND();       
        return resVec;
    }
```

Any ideas how I can pass not declared number of zeros? Or maybe any idea of different implementation? Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated: please please read about java naming conventions and follow them strictly. Class **and** interface names go UpperCase, always. Method names go lowerCase(), always too. Anything else confuses the hell out of your readers.

Comment: @GhostCat confuses the hell out of your readers **and** simplified syntax highlighters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the resVec() method, you can populate an array of 0s and then pass it to your Vector super constructor. Since your super constructor takes an array of ints, you could do something like this:

```
public VectorND resVec(int n)
{
    int[] coordinates = new int[n];
    Arrays.fill(coordinates, 0);

    VectorND resVec = new VectorND(coordinates);       
    return resVec;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work because resVec() doesn't expect any arguments so then I have unimplemented method error in VectorND

Comment: How else are you going to know the dimension of N when it is creating the array? You could have your interface method with no arguments as well, just have that method call the new one with a default value of 3 or something.

Answer (score 1):

Foremost you could make use of generics since you would get problems as soon you need float or double for a vector type.

```
public interface Vector<T extends Number>{

    T getX();

    void setX(T x);

    // [...]

    T length();

    T lengthSquared();
    // [...]
```

To your problem, it can be solved by adding a helper variable which contains the dimension amount and than process the math operations as algorthm / loop. This way the amount of dimension don't matter anymore and you also avoid issues like divide by zero.

this is a excample for a matrix .. but the aproche is the same:

```
public final void multiply(float factor) {
    // in your case it would be getDimension() or something 
    for(int i = 0; i < getRows()*getColumns();++i){
        m[i]*=factor;
    }
}
```

Oh and I know this advice is hard for java developer but don't over engineer it otherwise you will waste preformence.

Comment: The naming convention to go ISomething for interfaces ... is like very much uncommon these days.

Comment: Ok I have adjusted that to match a more common style.

Comment: You could also change the name to NumberVector ... just to avoid the overlap with the java.util.Number ... but that is a minor detail.

Comment: `Number` actually stands for `java.util.Number` in my case .. this is on purpose to pass in Double, Integer etc. ... the dimension count is not included in the name it would be handled by extending the interface. `public interface Vector3 extends Vector<Integer> {` as excample.

`public class Vector3I implements Vector3<Integer> {`

Comment: I know that. No, I meant `Vector` could be `NumberVector<T ...` ... but as said, minor detail.

Comment: @jans. I don't quiet see how this new method would infiltrate in my code where I declare new vector with abstract method and everything is connected to it

Comment: My answer just give a idea of different implementation aproch since you asked for ideas which would work. Sadly the excamples will not be directly compatible with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The values of arrays are automatically defaulted.

```
int[] ints = new int[4];             // Filled with 0
double[] doubles = new double[5];    // Filled with 0.0
boolean[] booleans = new boolean[6]; // Filled with false
String[] strings = new String[7];    // Filled with null
```

I am not entirely sure about your classes, but for a multi-dimensional matrix-like class one only needs *one* version. The values can be stored in a linearized array by using a calculated index.

```
public class DoubleMatrix {
    final int[] sizes;
    final double[] values;

    public DoubleMatrix(int... sizes) {
        this.sizes = Arrays.copyOf(sizes, sizes.length); // Or sizes.clone()
        int valueCount = 1;
        for (int size : this.sizes) {
            assert size > 0 : "Every given size must be at least 1.";
            valueCount *= size;
        }
        values = new int[valueCount];
    }

    public int dimesion() {
        return sizes.length;
    }

    public double get(int... is) {
        int i = index(is);
        return values[i];
    }

    // new DoubleMatrix(2, 3, 4).set(3.14259, 0, 1, 2); // 24 values in 3D
    public void set(double x, int... is) {
        int i = index(is);
        values[i] = x;
    }
```

The setter is a bit unconventional placing the value first because of the var-args `is`.
The linearisation from several indices to an index into the `values` array:

```
    private int index(int... is) {
        assert is.length == sizes.length: "Wrong number of indices.";
        int singleI = 0;
        for (int dim = 0; dim < sizes.length) {
            if (0 > is[dim] || is[dim] >= sizes[dim]) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
            if (dim > 0) {
                singleI *= sizes[i - 1];
            }
            singleI += is[i];
        }
    }
```

*(I am not sure the index calculation is correct.)*

Instead of asserts throwing runtime exceptions (IllegalArgumentException) would be better.

Of course if `get` and `set` were `protected` you could make a child class without var-args, and have a `public get(int i, int j)` for a `DoubleMatrix2D`.